# How to properly use this.destroy() in Kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am using javascript Kineticjs framework for creating a game for kids. More specifically, I am working with rectangles and groups. I have the following function which combines two cubes (by adding them in the same group) whenever they collide. What I wanted to implement is a double click event on the group which destroys it, as shown on the code below. For this, I am using this.destroy() function which seems to work fine (as can be seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javakammenos/e8t5J/) example taken from the official website and modified a bit).

```
/*
 A function that takes two cubes and add them in a group if the collide
*/
function combineCubes(movingCube,staticCube){
 var movingCube_x = movingCube.getAbsolutePosition().x;
 var movingCube_y = movingCube.getAbsolutePosition().y;
 var staticCube_x = staticCube.getAbsolutePosition().x;
 var staticCube_y = staticCube.getAbsolutePosition().y;

var tempGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    name:'group',
    draggable : true,
    dragOnTop: false
});

if ( collisionHappens(movingCube, staticCube) ) {
    movingCube.x(staticCube_x);
    movingCube.y(staticCube_y - staticCube.height());
    tempGroup.add(staticCube);
    tempGroup.add(movingCube);
    movingCube.setDraggable(false);
    staticCube.setDraggable(false);
    layer.add(tempGroup);
}

tempGroup.on('dblclick', function() {
        this.destroy();
    }   
 });
}
```

What happens when I use this code is that everything stops responding (I guess that there may be an infinite loop).

I am adding some sample code below which shows how I call the combineCubes() function.

```
/*
I am calling the combineCubes function inside another function.
*/

function createCube(tempX, tempY) {
  var tempCube = new Kinetic.Rect({
     x : tempX,
     y : tempY
  };
/*
At dragend of each cube I am checking if it is colliding with other cubes
*/
tempCube.on('dragend', function() {
    if(collisionHappens){
        combineCubes(this, anotherCube);
    }
 }
}
```

Even though I am not very familiar with Javascript, I think that this is mostly a Javascript problem rather than a KineticJS as I have the feeling that something is wrong with the scope of the variables inside functions. However, even though I have tried in using different techniques I didn't manage to make this work. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `.hide()` or `.remove()` ? I used the second method and worked fine, I don't know about `.destroy()`.

```
tempGroup.on("dblclick dbltap", function(e){
     this.remove(); //or .hide()
     layer.draw(this);
     stage.draw(); 
});
```